# how to modify code block tool of ckeditor to save a code content with dark background?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, ckeditor

I am new to ckeditor. I want to save a block of html code content in database with dark background style in ckeditor.

But after saving to database with axios, when the data is fetched through api it is not maintaining the style. It is coming as plain text. Please help.

Or is there any way to send custom css styles along with api and save that style to database ?

```
<md-card-content>
                <ckeditor
                    v-model="lesson.content"
                    :editor="editor"
                    :config="editorConfig"
                  ></ckeditor>
            </md-card-content>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" @click="updateContent">
Update
            </button>
```